# Generating managable log files on a batch file job

Tags: logging, batch-file, batch-processing

I am running a robocopy job through a batch file that is scheduled to run every hour. I am using the following switches:

Robocopy \servername\share D:\somedir /E /R:5  /Log+:D:\Logs\CopyLog.txt

It has been working faithfully for a long time but it ran into a snag this morning. I went to check the log file and was suprised to find it had grown to just shy of 280 Mb.

My question then is how I can change my batchfile to write more managable log files? I think it would make sense to append on a period for which it is reported in. ie: CopyLog_201103.txt would be the log file for March 2011.

I'm fairly adept at working with higher level programming languages, but command line programming was already long gone by the time I was growing up. I'm definitely learning the value of getting a firm understanding of the much more basic computer concepts.

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the day, month and year using this cmd snippet:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%d in ('%date%') do (
    set day=%%d
    set month=%%e
    set year=%%f
)
```

(Warning: locale specific.)

Now you can write to different log files as you see fit.

Comment: @Curtis: Careful though; you should not use that method in production code that needs to run on machines you do not control since you need to know the date format for that to work.

Comment: @joey: Agreed. Someone pointed this command out as an alternative: `wmic os get localdatetime`. (EDIT: hah! I see you have it in your answer below.)

Comment: Yep ;-) I still have to write a useful script around it but for a one-off quick & dirty appraoch it works fairly well (with the caveat that it uses UTC, although I'd take for granted in log files). I've been quite happy when I discovered that that's actually something to get the current date and time in a locale-unspecific way (which I didn't know to be even possible in batch files until then).

Answer (score 3):

#### Ugly way (not recommended, but needed on Windows 2000 and earlier):

```
set MyDate=%DATE:-=%
set Filename=D:\Logs\CopyLog_%MyDate:~0,6%
robocopy ... /Log+:%Filename%
```

Note: This assumes ISO-8601 as the short date format on your system. If that's not the case, then you need to construct the date from substrings of `%date%`.

#### Locale-proof way:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%d
set Filename=D:\Logs\CopyLog_%MyDate:~0,6%
robocopy ... /Log+:%Filename%
```